# How to change menu structure?

Tags: menus, filters

When we show the menu using `wp_nav_menu`, it creates menu with a structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      <a class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a class="link" href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a class="link" href="#">Link 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I change it to be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  <a href="#">Item 4</a>
  <a href="#">Item 5</a>
</div>
```

---

I tried to customize it by filter, but I'm not able to check menu by arguments, the arguments just coming NULL.

My code is like this:

```
// page.php
wp_nav_menu([ 'theme_location' => 'sidebar_menu' ]);

// functions.php
function custom_menu($items, $args) {
    // ....
    print_r($args); // NULL
}

apply_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'custom_menu');
```

Comment: It's also possible to do this with a custom menu walker class, and may be possible using the options in the `wp_nav_menu` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customizing menu markup can only be accomplished by adding a WordPress filter and using your own, custom menu template.

Unfortunately, menus are not a part of the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) so you need to do something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', function( $nav_menu, $args ) {
  if( 'my_custom_menu' == $args->menu->slug ) {
    // include a template with your required markup
    // reference both the $nav_menu and $args params in the template
    return include('my-nav-template.php');
  } else {
    return $nav_menu;
  }
}, 10, 2);
```

This is a somewhat abbreviated answer. You'll need to read the WordPress documentation on the [nav_menu object / function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) in order to know exactly how to parse the object but it's pretty straight forward.

Also, be sure that sidebar_menu is registered *before* calling `wp_nav_menu()` and that at least one menu has been assigned to the sidebar before trying this code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! It might solve my problem

Comment: Feel free to write back with follow-up questions. I'll reply eventually :)

Comment: Additional questions should be started in their own thread.

Comment: Hey @TedStresen-Reuter, I'm not able to get anything from `$args`, it's coming `NULL`. I updated my question with sample code.

Comment: I tweaked my answer (fixed a variable name and the function call). Please re-read what I wrote and try again. I've verified this solution works (for me!)

Comment: Hey @TedStresen-Reuter, I tried to customize my menu by `Walker`, but I'm not able to get `start_lvl` works (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346343/start-lvl-on-walker-is-not-working)

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with what you've got so far. There really are many ways to make this work but without seeing more of your code, I can't really comment. Also, in a new question, with your sample code, more people will be able to guide you. A Walker is probably the best way to go but again, to help I would need to see the code and a new question will keep things clearer for others. HTH.