# start_lvl on Walker is not working

Tags: menus, walker

I'm creating a custom Walker to my menu, my code is like this:

```
<?php

class My_Walker extends Walker {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "<nav>";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</nav>";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        $output .= "<li>My Item</li>";  //This is just a sample <li>
    }
}
```

The `start_el` is working fine, but `start_lvl` and `end_lvl` is not working at all.

The rendered HTML is like this:

[image: list code sample]

Why is my `start_lvl` and `end_lvl` not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your menu doesn't appear to have any levels. `start_lvl` and `end_lvl` are used for the *sub*-menu wrappers. The outer wrapper for the menu, the `<ul`> is defined by the `items_wrap` argument of `wp_nav_menu()`:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    [
        'walker'     => new My_Walker(),
        'items_wrap' => '<nav id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</nav>',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks! it works!